# Stubbing Gmaps4rails with geocoding.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, gmaps4rails

I've reviewed a few of the Gmaps4rails stubbing questions and think I'm very close, but not quite there.  Forgive me: Very new to stubbing and mocking in rails.

All of this code works in the real world, just trying to get it to skip geocoding during testing.  Right now tests *sometimes* work and *sometimes* fail with the **Gmaps4rails address Address invalid** error

So, I have a very simple party.rb model that acts_as_gmappable:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
   "#{self.city}, #{self.country}" 
end
```

I've pasted geocoding.rb from github and placed it in /spec/support unmodified

However, I can't seem to tell my parties_controller_spec to use the stub instead of the real one.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple...  I've tried:

```
include Geocoding
```

and even

```
Gmaps4rails.set_gmaps4rails_options!({:msg => "quack"})
```

and I don't see "quack" as the error message, I see **Validation failed: Gmaps4rails address Address invalid**

Also tried:

```
Gmaps4rails.set_gmaps4rails_options!({:validation => false, :check_process => false, :process_geocoding => false})
```

But to no effect.

My factories.rb has a straightforward :party define:

```
Factory.define :party do |party|
party.name      "Thai New Year"
party.city      "Phuket"
party.country   "Thailand"
...
end
```

So, I'm pretty sure I haven't properly told rspec to use the stubbed Gmaps4rails.  So, where exactly do I put the code that tells Gmaps4rails to use your stub_geocoding method instead of actually trying to perform geocoding?

Any help would be appreciated... Sorry if this is a mundane question.

Dave

Comment: what options do you have in acts_as_gmappable (if any)

Comment: No options on acts_as_gmappable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this if you don't want any geocoding:

```
Factory.define :party do |party|
  party.name      "Thai New Year"
  party.city      "Phuket"
  party.country   "Thailand"
  party.gmaps     true #<= this is what tells the gem not to fire geocoding
  party.latitude  whatever_if_relevant
  party.longitude whatever_if_relevant
  ...
end
```

Comment: Bam!  That did it!  I knew it would be less than 30 characters of code! :-).  BTW Gmaps4rails is awesome!!